# Direct construction of equalizers in $\mathbf {Top}$

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I'm trying to prove (directly) the existence of equalizers in the category of topological spaces.

First let $s,t:X\to Y$ be continuous maps of topological spaces. Let $E=\{x\in X:s(x)=t(x)\}$ and $i:E\to X$ the inclusion map. $E$ has the subset topology, and $i$ is continuous.

Suppose $f: A\to X$ is a continuous map of topological spaces s.t. $sf=tf$. There is a map of sets $\bar f: A\to E, \bar f(a)=f(a)$ such that $f=i\bar f$. The problem is to show that $\bar f$ is continuous.

Let $U\subset E$ be open (so $U=E\cap V$ where $V\subset X$ is open, and also $U=i^{-1}(V)$). We need to prove that $\bar f^{-1}(U)\subset A$ is open. We have $$\bar f^{-1}(U)=\{a\in A:\bar f(a)\in U\}\\=\{a\in A:f(a)\in U\}\\=f^{-1}(U)$$

If we knew that $U\subset X$ is open, then $f^{-1}(U)\subset A$ would be open, and hence $\bar f^{-1}(U)\subset A$ would be open. But why is $U$ open in $X$ (and is it)? We only know it's open in $E$.

Comment: $E$ is the equalizer in $\textsf{Set}$ and as $i\tilde{f}=f$ and $i$ induces the initial topology on $E$, $\tilde{f}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have $f: A \to X$ such that $sf=tf$. This means that actually as sets $f[A] \subseteq E$. So define $g: X \to E$ by $g(a)=f(a)$ for all $a \in A$ and this is a well-defined function and $ig=f$ is trivial. It is continuous as a co-domain restriction of a continuous map: $O$ is open in $E$ iff it is of the form $i^{-1}[U]$ for $U$ open in $X$ and $g^{-1}[O]= g^{-1}[i^{-1}[U]] = (ig)^{-1}[U]=f^{-1}[U]$ so $g$ is continuous. Note that I just use the same $g$ as the equalizer in $\mathsf{Set}$ and use only that $i$ induces the initial topology on it to show its continuity ( a map $g$ into $E$ is continuous iff $i \circ g$ is continuous).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You’re right, $U$ is probably not open in $X$, but don’t you have an open set of $X$ associated to $U$ you could work with?

Comment: I could work with $V$, but I don't see how knowing that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open can help to prove that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open (which is what I need, as far as I understand).

Comment: @user634426 Think about the relationship between $f^{-1}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(U)$, given that $f$ has image contained in $E$.

Comment: Do you mean $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(V)\cap f^{-1}(E)$ and since $f(A)\subset E$, $f^{-1}(E)=\{a\in A: f(a)\in E\}=A$; so $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(V)$?

Comment: @user634426 Yep!